# The 3 keys of the past

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, story

### The key to this puzzle is the past

You don't need another hint...

> NOTE:
> 3 Keys are NOT on keyboard. They lead to a single key on the keyboard. Also note that everything is involved in the answer, I don't do red herrings

Comment: Sorry to those who actually saw the puzzle, this was supposed to be the first clue leading to it

Comment: Aaaaaah thats clever. For anyone who hasn't realised yet you need to click on something to actually get the puzzle. I like the past clue

Comment: great puzzle OP! +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm tempted to say:

> Esc

Because

> First look in the edit history for the complete puzzle because 'The key to this puzzle is in the past', I had help from @Moose's answer and @Joe's comment! Then, from the noticeboard, ski sounds like 'S key' and the note is a middle C. If the map can be interpreted as E.. then in order the keys spell out ESC. This could also match the poem line ending 'and ever be free' or escape.

Shout out to @kayzeroshort:

> As commented: "you can get the 'E' from the map by taking the nth letter of each map feature, where n is the given number. (4 - rivEr, 4 - lanE, 2 - sEcondary road)"

I wouldn't bet my life on it though!

> Maybe I should have! I actually thought I was wrong because of the hint.. technically they aren't on the keyboard (they're on the noticeboard), but their interpretations E, S and C certainly are!

Comment: was about to try this.  you can get the 'E' from the map by taking the nth letter of each map feature, where n is the given number. (4 - rivEr, 4 - lanE, 2 - sEcondary road)

Comment: @Arth well done this is correct

Comment: If you add in @kayzeroshort's comment then i will accept

Comment: Thanks @BeastlyGerbil, see my note for a potential confusion. Thoroughly enjoyable puzzle :)

Comment: `This key is special` further proves this answer is correct. The key you are talking about is special (function keys, modifier keys, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Very much a work in progress:

> I noticed the puzzle had been edited, so I clicked to look at the edit history. Looking at "the past" edits, you can find a real puzzle.

Once you go there:

> The noticeboard has a topographical map, which I don't yet understand. But then it has the word "SKI" and middle C.

The note:

> *To open this door you’ll need a key,*
> *If you want to enter and ever be free,*
> *This key is special, its hard to find,*
> *If your puzzled now, then use your mind*
>
> *Below is a keyboard, a key you must press,*
> *Get it wrong and you die, so do not guess!*
> *Find the correct one by finding 3 other keys,*
> *Here’s a test of your puzzling expertise*

My guess at (one of) the three keys:

> It would make sense for each image on the noticeboard to lead to one of the keys, so here is my attempt at deciphering that:
>  The map: unknown 
>  The word "SKI": unknown 
>  The whole note "C": this is actually middle c, the key on a piano which is closest to the middle. However, the row of keys on a piano is called the keyboard, so this may be trying to lead us that the key to press is towards the middle of our keyboard.

Comment: the note isn't e

Comment: Oops I was thinking bass clef

Comment: I'm afraid you are entirely incorrect, only one key should be pressed on the keyboard. The three keys lead to that one key

Comment: Ah, I took the three keys to literally mean keys on the keyboard that lead you to the one key. May I ask if the grammatical inconsistency is at all pertinent?

Comment: The three keys might be the "a", "enter" and "3" keys. these are in the note and are real keys on the keyboard. However, don't know how to find a single key from these three.

Comment: @Meta45, your wrong i'm afraid. Don't know why no one has considered looking at the noticeboard for the three keys (Which are NOT keys on the keyboard)....

Comment: Still wrong, keep trying though you are looking in the right place now